# Unit testing and alternative to mocking in Haskell

Tags: haskell, unit-testing, mocks

Let's say you have a simple pure function that applies a discount of 30% if the total price of a list of `Item`s is over 30.00 (let's not delve into the fact that I'm using a `Float` to indicate the price):

```hs
promoGet30PercentOff :: [Item] -> Float
promoGet30PercentOff xs
  | total > 30.0 = total * 0.7
  | otherwise    = total
  where total = sum $ map itemPrice xs
```

and `Item` and `itemPrice` are defined as follows:

```hs
data Item = Apple | Banana deriving Show

itemPrice :: Item -> Float
itemPrice x =
  case x of
    Apple -> 5.9
    Banana -> 3.0
```

I'd now like to test `promoGet30PercentOff` at the boundary.
As I come from Python, my natural reaction would be to mock `Item` and create some that are priced at 30.0, 30.1 and 0.0, for instance.

I believe, this is not possible in Haskell (but correct me if I'm wrong).
How would you go about it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can untangle your promo function from the `Item` data type

```
promoGet30PercentOffWith :: (a -> Float) -> [a] -> Float
promoGet30PercentOffWith price xs
  | total > 30.0 = total * 0.7
  | otherwise    = total
  where total = sum $ map price xs

promoGet30PercentOff :: [Item] -> Float
promoGet30PercentOff = promoGet30PercentOffWith itemPrice
```

Because `promoGet30PercentOffWith` is polymorphic, there is a [free theorem](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/99370.99404) that all functions of its type satisfy:

```
promoGet30PercentOffWith f xs = promoGet30PercentOffWith id (map f xs)
```

This means that the general behavior of that function is entirely determined by its specialized behavior when the first argument is `id`---so the list argument has type `[Float]`. Thus, mocking items with artificial prices is as simple as giving the list of prices to the function.

```
shouldPromo :: [Float] -> IO ()
shouldPromo xs = promoGet30PercentOffWith id xs === sum xs * 0.7

shouldNotPromo :: [Float] -> IO ()
shouldNotPromo xs = promoGet30PercentOffWith id xs === sum xs

(===) :: Eq a => a -> a -> IO ()
x === y = if x == y then return () else error "assertion failed"

test :: IO ()
test = do
  shouldPromo [30.1]
  shouldNotPromo [30.0]
  shouldNotPromo [0]
```